# Android How to preview an image, using its file path from SDcard, from my application

Tags: android, image, view, preview

File is present in `sdcard/image.jpg`
I would like to create my own application (activity).
On a button press, the image stored in the sdcard needs to be displayed using the built-in image viewer.
On pressing the back button from the Image viewer, it should go back to my running application.

Need some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

This code use for display all images from your SD card

Answer (score 11):

you can create an Intent with proper uri and mimetype for this.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/image.jpg"), "image/jpeg");
startActivity(i);
```