# How to implement SD Card Gallery without customization in android?

Tags: android, implementation, gallery, sd-card

How to implement `SD Card Gallery` into our application directly?

I know it is possible in iphone . We can implement and access photos of sdcard directly without any customization in iphone.

I want to implement the same interface of `Gallery` into android app.

Please let me know...

Thank you.

Comment: You sure about the iPhone part of the question? iPhones do not support sdcards so the point that "it is possible in iPhone" is kind of a moot point.

Comment: Oh... sorry. Now only i know about iphone does not support SD Card. I noticed the photos album of iphone has been implemented into app directly. Thats why wanted to know the possiblity in android..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to get you started.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

and this one will give you a rough idea too. Of course, you will have to improvise later to make it function just the way you want it to.

[Android How to preview an image, using its file path from SDcard, from my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820949/android-how-to-preview-an-image-using-its-file-path-from-sdcard-from-my-applica)